# getting pre-translated element text in Google Tag Manager GTM

Tags: google-analytics, translation, google-tag-manager

I have some click events in my GTM container and I'm using the Click Text and Element Text variables to grab the text of the link and sending it as the Event Label to Google Analytics.

The problem I'm encountering now is that some users are visiting the site and translating it to their preferred language and the translated text is being sent to GA as the label.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to get the original english text?

Maybe there's a way to hook into the translating process to run code before it translates?